# Longpolling AJAX after implementing Unity Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have implemented Unity.mvc3 into my project but now my Knockout AJAX methods are starting a Longpolling process and I do not know why, can anyone help please?

> This is the JSON response (I have not got a clue why I am getting
>   this)- {"C":"d-13044D90-B,0|E,2|F,0","M":[]}
>
> A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1764%2Findex.html&browserName=Chrome&tid=5&_=1403698144789
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK Request Headersview source
>   Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8 Cache-Control:no-cache
>   Connection:keep-alive Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8
>   Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=j6VFekQ7Po1EfD9wSUK4e4A_ts1SVuGIbRwDG727whnb8l--9P5v5maO-FhCOjFLitRIegjYixEX9698kZR_JWHvo7lUmFYfOwVNjwQ7Hhg1
>   Host:localhost:7356
>
> Pragma:no-cache
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36 Query String
>   Parametersview sourceview URL encoded transport:longPolling
>   connectionToken:AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAANVlw/ETQ70WfNHf1KMvu6gAAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAACnUs1Jjk7unYzODmvpJNj7Nbvay/Dx4kSOH+V/CtVDTwAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAAAm7NaW0uCoayuqpNT8z8+uLy/Uio+Nbh8g+VDE0X1/8TAAAAAKXR/1gbPBSIz2WagA2zJI6Te45f63pWeiYkXBGYlYeO+WbWbkTycWNrGmRqaUY8JAAAAAsCIr6JEw/gAUfIClKEjm3cBXG3+I33yhob1f3jMrvmLQTeDC7hphp1SAz+utVN28VstEmeExHyyuycRP/upWIw==
>   messageId:d-13044D90-B,0|E,2|F,0
>
> browserName:Chrome tid:5
>   _:1403698144789 Response Headersview source Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>
> Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8 Date:Wed, 25 Jun 2014
>   12:09:10 GMT Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Transfer-Encoding:chunked
>   X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is the answer,  add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" to the web config between the appSettings tags the automatic polling has stopped, I found out this happens by default in VS2012 and now no more auto polling :-) -  . I also cannot believe no one posted anything for this but anyways this worked a treat.